# Current expression after closing the switch

Tags: circuit-analysis, kirchhoffs-laws

In the picture below the switch \$S_1\$ is open for a long time, and I need to find the expression of \$i(t)\$ for \$t>0\$ (when \$S_1\$ closes):

[image]

Since this is an RLC circuit, I need to solve a second order ODE.  I found \$i(0)=4\mathrm{ A}\$ and $$\frac{di(0)}{dt}=28\mathrm{ A/s}$$ as initial conditions to be able to solve that ODE (if someone could double check those values, that would be great).

After \$S_1\$ is closed, the \$30\Omega\$ resistor is short-circuited and the \$10\Omega\$ and \$20\Omega\$ resistors are in parallel, so we get the following circuit:

[image]

I have tried using both Kirchhoff's laws but couldn't find that ODE. Any ideas how can I proceed here?

Attempt using KCL:

[image]

**NODE A**:

$$6=i_c+i_2$$

$$6=0.15\frac{dv_c}{dt}+\frac{v_c-0}{6.667} \tag{1}$$

**NODE 0**:

$$i_2=i+i_3$$

$$\frac{v_c-0}{6.667}\ = i + \frac{0-v_L}{15}\tag{2}$$

**Replacing (2) in (1)**:

$$6=0.15\frac{dv_c}{dt}+i - \frac{v_L}{15}$$

$$6=0.15\frac{dv_c}{dt}+i -\frac{1}{15}\frac{di_3}{dt}$$

$$6=0.15\frac{dv_c}{dt}+i -\frac{1}{15}\frac{d(i_2-i)}{dt}$$

$$6=0.15\frac{dv_c}{dt}+i +\frac{1}{15}\frac{di}{dt}-\frac{1}{15}\frac{di_2}{dt}$$

$$6=0.15\frac{dv_c}{dt}+i +\frac{1}{15}\frac{di}{dt}-\frac{1}{15}\frac{d(6-i_c)}{dt}$$

$$6=0.15\frac{dv_c}{dt}+i +\frac{1}{15}\frac{di}{dt}+\frac{1}{15}\frac{di_c}{dt}$$

This is as far as I could go trying to get that second order ODE for \$i(t)\$.

Comment: @Antonio51 I first tried finding the ODE using KCL, but didn't succeed. Then i tried KVL, but could't make it either.

Comment: Check this. When switch is closed, R-L alone at the left, R-C-I alone at the right ... Two First Order equations.

Comment: Show us your work. There is no point in asking someone to redo **everything** that you have done.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson The work is there. I have found all the initial and final conditions of my desired variable i(t). I have found the equivalent circuit after the switch have been closed. But i still can't find a second order ODE for i(t), like i have read in books we should find to solve a RLC circuit, or two first order ODE like Antonio sugested (never heard we could do that, but i tried anyway). I have added a new picture showing my attempt using KCL in the top nodes.

Comment: Have you the initial condition before closing the switch? When you close the switch, it is obvious that the first loop (L-R) is alone with a "initial" inductor current. So, after closing the switch, current in the self is an exponentially decreasing function starting at 2 A -> you have the first part of your i(t) current ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check first this, switch open. Dynamic DC analysis. [Microcap v12](http://www.spectrum-soft.com/download/download.shtm).
This will give you the "initial" condition of the **inductor current** and **voltage capacitor** ... for the two "independent" loops ... after closing the switch.

After closing the switch, "i(t)" is composed of two parts: current1 from the left, current2 from the right, from independent loops.

[image]

> Since this is an RLC circuit, I need to solve a second order ODE.

Are you sure?

Perhaps two first-order independent equations, then one add the solutions?

This simulation could help you.
Check the variables you need.

[image]

Comment: I finally solved it! The two first order ODE helped a lot, until yesterday, i didn't knew we could do that to solve a RLC circuit. One more question, wich software did you use to simulate that circuit? It's a free software? or commercial one?

Comment: FULL FREE software with many examples. Check the link in answer.

Comment: I tried click the link, but nothing happened. I will Google it, Sepctrum Software Microcap?

Comment: Spectrum Software - Micro-Cap 12. Analog simulation, mixed ...http://www.spectrum-soft.com go to Download ... microcap v12 full CD

Comment: Link corrected in answer ... Search also newsletters

Answer (score 1):

### Intuitive analysis.

[image]

Fig a)
switch open, 6A source , 10 Ohm load = 60V source.  Vsw=30V, IL= 2A
[image]

Fig b)
switch closed. 6A source, 10||20 = 6.67 ohm load, Vsource= I*R = 40V
Parallel L/R discharge loop on left , Parallel RC discharge loop on right of switch from 60 to 40 V. You figure out the details of exponential slopes.
;)